# Weird behavior of configuration in OpenRC init script

Tags: shell, init-script, openrc

I'm trying to make a simple OpenRC init script for a service.
What I have so far looks like this:

```
#!/sbin/openrc-run

CONFIG=${CONFIG:-/etc/pysystemfan.json}

pidfile=${PIDFILE:-/var/run/pysystemfan.pid}
command=${COMMAND:-/usr/sbin/pysystemfan}
command_arguments="--config ${CONFIG}"
required_files="\"$CONFIG"\"
start_stop_daemon_args="--background"
```

The idea of this is that `CONFIG`, `PIDFILE` and `COMMAND` can be set from the corresponding conf.d file.

My problem is that the script seems to be run once with the config.d file loaded ("Caching dependencies"), and then without it when actually starting the service.

Why is this? I've tried looking at other init scripts and I didn't notice any real difference between how they handle settings and how I do it.

Comment: did you try `rc-update -u` after adding the script?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried it, but it doesn't help. It seems that the update is done automatically every time I change the init script.

Comment: did you declare `start()` and `stop()` functions in your script?

Comment: No, I'm using the defaults. The snippet in my question is the complete init script. If I hardcode the values instead of attempting to pass them from `conf.d`, then everything works correctly.

Comment: Nothing strange then. At least `start()` has to be defined (there can be no stop thought). And all of yours variables have to be passed to the `start-stop-daemon`

Answer (score 0):

From docs ast [1]:

> Every init script requires the start() function to be defined. All
>   other sections are optional.

[1] - https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:X86/Working/Initscripts